# Multitennant Datasource locations for treelist

Tags: sitecore-query, tree-list

For input fields which support the query syntax its no problem like

```
Droplist
Grouped Droplist
DropLink
Grouped Droplink
Checklist
Multilist
Droptree
```

here I am using the following query

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Seite']/Global/Faq/*
```

and here I only need to follow naming conventions in all my tennants and then this should work fine.

but how do you handle

```
Treelist
TreelistEx
```

here the query syntax is not working and I don't know how to make the datasource Items Multitennant avaiable

Treelist
TreelistEx